# Flow works when a specific column in the SQL table changes in Power Automate

Tags: sql-server, triggers, power-automate

I am creating a flow in Power Automate according to the relevant conditions in my SQL table. I'm currently working on making the flow run when a specific column in my table changes, but I couldn't do it. For example, I have a `person` table and this person table has hundreds of columns. In this person table, I have a column called "`personType`". This column can take integer values such as 1,2,3,4. What I want is to capture only the person type changes in this table and run the relevant flow. In other words, it may change in other columns in this table. But I don't want those changes to run the relevant flow. Let the relevant flow run only when "`personType`" changes.
Creating a flow that captures only `personType` column changes

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking for SQL assistance. Don't forget to include your current code attempt.

Comment: And add a tag for the dbms used. (Most products have their own trigger syntax.)